# Use value returned by a unix shell script then assign it to downstreamParameterized in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I have this entry in our dsl.groovy

```
downstreamParameterized {
  trigger('apache_server') {
    parameters {
      predefinedProp('APP_PACKAGE_VERSION', "\${APP_PACKAGE_VERSION}")
    }
  }
}
```

If you notice, the value is coming from APP_PACKAGE_VERSION in stringParam. What I'd like to happen is use the value that is being returned by my unix script(this script already exists). How should I write the code in groovy?

Comment: I found a solution using  EnvInject plugin but what is the code for this in dsl.groovy?

Answer (score 0):

*Job DSL* uses Groovy and Groovy includes the `execute` method to `String` to make executing shells possible:

```
println "script.sh".execute().text
```

You can learn more about it by following this [article](http://www.joergm.com/2010/09/executing-shell-commands-in-groovy/).

Call to `execute()` will be resolved during by Job DSL engine. Therefore generated project will already have output value.

If you would like to call your script each time job is build, I suggest using [Groovy plug-in](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin).

Comment: Here is what I did in our dsl.groovy and it worked pretty well. SOME_VAR = sprintf('\${%s}', ['SOME_VAR'])

Comment: I'm also not sure what we are using. I've seen different dsl.groovy file from different teams but I didn't see any code containing "def"

Comment: @devwannabe How does this solution relate to getting output from shell script?

Comment: The value is just persistent. It just works. It's both in parameters { stringParams: ""} and in shell(SOME_VAR) command

Answer (score -1):

If that's is environment variable for Jenkins then you can use like  this

```
foo = build.buildVariableResolver`.resolve("FOO")
println "FOO=$foo"
```

Refer https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin

Comment: I actually got it to work using "Inject environment variables" and env.properties file. However, I need to convert it so that it is inside dsl.groovy.